# Javascript is not working in Bootstrap navbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I am using bootstrap navbar and I'm not sure why my javascript is not working below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".nav a").on("click", function () {
    $(".nav").find(".active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).parent().addClass("active");
});
</script>
```

The following is included in my layout:

```
<!-- jQuery -->
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery");
<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap");
```

here is part of my code that's having issue, Please advise thank you!

```
               <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Reports</a>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Weekly Tickets</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Yearly Tickets</a></li>
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Status <span class="caret"></span></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="@Url.Action("ViewChartsByYearMonth", "Charts")">Per Month</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="@Url.Action("ViewCharts", "Charts")">Per Year</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Severity<span class="caret"></span></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="#">Per Month</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Per Year</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
```

Comment: what do you mean by not working?please check console for errors

Comment: The navbar active state is not working. it doesn't change.

Comment: whenever i include another source    <script src="~/Scripts/js/jquery.js"></script> the javascript works but then the dropdown functionality of the navbar doesn't work.

Comment: please check console if you have error

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap it in jQuery Document ready, also

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".nav a").on("click", function () {
    $(".nav").find(".active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).parent().addClass("active");
  });
});
```

also better use: ("ul.nav").find("li.active").removeClass("active");

....Better put your console log for debugging, but make sure your jQuery not conflicting with other Javascript frameworks too...

Also check if jQuery pointed to the right URL...